# Ввод тега в текстовое поле

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Здравствуйте. Есть проблема с вводом данных в текстовые поля. Табличка в которую помещаются данные, формируется с помощью Table и постепенным собиранием её. Т.е. в Table записываются TableRow в них в свою очередь TableCell и туда запихиваются данные. Проблема в следующем. Допустим в тестовое поле записываем произвольный текст и перед этим текстом пишем `<d` например. То в результате в этом столбце будет пусто. Получается `<d` как то преобразуется в html тэг. И данных не видно. Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Попробовал написать `<d>` а потом уже текст и действительно текст отображается а теги нет. И всё нормально. То есть действительно `<d` воспринимался как открытый тег и поэтому текста не было видно.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как можно устранить эту уязвимость?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Поробуйте прогонять ваш текст через HttpUtility.HtmlEncode.

> HtmlEncode(String)     Преобразует строку в строку в кодировке HTML.

[Источник](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Пример:

```
using System.Web;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<d"); //result = &lt;d
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сергей, спасибо, ещё есть вариант, `SecurityElement.Escape` тоже подходящий.

Comment: @Андрей, пожалуйста) Про SecurityElement.Escape не знал. Учту)